# seing a static variable with hexdump

Tags: c, security, hexdump

I am preparing myself for a lecture exam on security aspects of software development. I would like to know if it is always possible to read the value of a static char array from a binary with hexdump?

If not on what factors does it depend whether I can read the value of it or not with a hexeditor??

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can locate the variable in the memory, you can read it with a hexdump - that's what hexdump programs are for.  How easy it is to locate depends on how much information you have about the binary and on what you know about its expected contents.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming C, yes, in the simple case.  However, there are methods to obfuscate such variables to limit reverse engineering.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but only if it is initialized at compile time. You could get more from a core dump or a debugger.